# Using ImageView and Swipe View in a single linear layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, swipeview

I want my layout as:
An ImageView on top, then Swipe Tabs.

I created a Tabbed Activity; in it's activity.xml file there's a tag

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager />
```

with its attributes.
I tried to put this tag inside a linear layout i.e.

```
LinearLayout
   ImageView
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager />
```

but the ImageView goes inside all the fragments.

Instead, I want it to be on top.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="packageName" />
```

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add the code you currently have to your question? That'll make helping you find a solution easier.

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting

Comment: Code added @SaschaM78

Comment: What all you need more? @SaschaM78